# Convert string column to integer

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, int

I have a dataframe like below

```
    a   b
0   1   26190
1   5   python
2   5   580
```

I want to make column `b` to host only integers, but as you can see `python` is not int convertible, so I want to delete the row at index `1`. My expected out put has to be like

```
    a   b
0   1   26190
1   5   580
```

How to filter and remove using pandas in python?

Comment: I found a work around here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns. But this only replaces the bad data with NaN

Comment: Use it: convert to int then dropna against the column to get rid of the rows

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df.b, errors='coerce'))
0    26190.0
1        NaN
2      580.0
Name: b, dtype: float64

print (pd.to_numeric(df.b, errors='coerce').notnull())
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: b, dtype: bool

df = df[pd.to_numeric(df.b, errors='coerce').notnull()]
print (df)

   a      b
0  1  26190
2  5    580
```

Another solution by comment of [Boud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694192/convert-string-column-to-integer/39694974#comment66688077_39694192) - use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and last convert to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df.b = pd.to_numeric(df.b, errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['b'])
df.b = df.b.astype(int)
print (df)
   a      b
0  1  26190
2  5    580
```

---

If need check all rows with bad data use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) - filter all data where after applying function `to_numeric` get `NaN`:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df.b, errors='coerce').isnull())
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: b, dtype: bool

print (df[pd.to_numeric(df.b, errors='coerce').isnull()])
   a       b
1  5  python
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 5, 5],
                   'b' : [26190, 'python', 580]})
df
   a       b
0  1   26190
1  5  python
2  5     580

df['b'] = np.where(df.b.str.contains('[a-z]') == True, np.NaN, df.b)
df
   a      b
0  1  26190
1  5    NaN
2  5    580

df = df.dropna()
df
   a      b
0  1  26190
2  5    580
```

You use the regex to identify strings, then convert these to `np.NaN` using `np.where` then drop them from the df with `df.dropna()`.